# Why does num_rows give me the number of all rows in the table?

Tags: php, mysql

So I have this code... I have been struggling with this for some time, and I'm guessing I'm doing something stupidly wrong.

```
function checkExistance($username, $password, $name, $surname, $company, $website, $db) 
    {
    include ("../includes/dataConnecti.php");
    $query = "SELECT * FROM loginportaltemp WHERE username = ? OR website = ?";
    if ($stmt = $dbi->prepare($query))
    {
        $stmt->bind_param('ss', $username, $website);                   
        $stmt->execute();               
        $stmt->store_result();
        if($stmt->num_rows > 0) 
        {
            header ("Location: ../foutje.php");
        }
        else {
            $stmt->close();             
            redirectCorrect($username, $password, $name, $surname, $company, $website, $db);
        }       
    }
    else
    {
        header ("../test.php");
    }
}
```

The Mysqli connection comes from the included dataConnecti.php
The `$stmt->num_rows`always gives 21, which in my case, are all the rows I have in the table.
This function is supposed to check if the user already exists.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Tip: after `header("Location....` use `die` to stop the execution.

Comment: @ojovirtual Thank you very much! Tips are always appreciated! I'm at it.

Comment: kudo's for foutje.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used `OR` in the query

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM loginportaltemp WHERE username = ? OR website = ?";
```

May be both the website & username count is 21

Comment: I'm going to check if this was it

Comment: Yes this was it... Great answer! Such a stupid mistake. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Sj03rs, if it solves your problem, mark it as answer.

Comment: Yes, thank you! The 10 minute timer of StackOverflow was a bit in the way :P